# how to prove the following result?

Tags: ring-theory

The ideal $(4,t)$ is not a power of ideal $(2,t)$ in ring $\mathbb Z[t]$.

I have no idea how to prove this?

I am assuming that let  $(4,t)$ is power of $(2,t)$ and trying for some contradiction. Is this possible that $3$ is in this ideal? i don't think so.

Comment: $3$ is in neither ideal, so why are you considering that element?

Comment: ohh sorry, let me edit it

Comment: @Tobias Kildetoft   it is written in my notes that $3$ is in $(4,t)$ but not in any power of $(2,t)$ which doesn't seems correct. because if $3$ comes there then $1$ will be there and it will be full ring

Comment: Well, then your notes are obviously wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ n \geq 2$. $(2,t)^n \subset (2^n,2^{n-1}t,t^2)$, hence $t \notin (2,t)^n$.

Probably, in your notes, you swapped $3$ and $t$.

Comment: thanks . may be $t$ is written there.